# Getting text in response instead of response body

Tags: chai

I am using chai to get response body. Instead, I always get my desired result in text. I have tried:

```
.post('xyz.com/server')
.set('Cookie', 'somevalue=1234')
.set('content-type', 'application/json')
```

When I print out my response object, I never get body. This is how my response looks like:

```
"header": {
"x-powered-by": "Express",
"access-control-allow-origin": "*",
"access-control-allow-headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
"access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
"access-control-allow-methods": "Content-Type",
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"content-length": "107",
"etag": "W/\"6b-rgYrpZXb7TdJm/JOuUivlL3U1fA\"",
"vary": "Accept-Encoding",
"date": "Wed, 31 Jan 2018 19:38:24 GMT",
"connection": "close"
},
"status": 200,
"text": "{\"err\":\"1006\",\"errDesc\":\"Sorry, your request could not be completed at this time. Please try again later.\"}"
}
```

I need that text to come in body. Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

The temporary solution is to use JSON.parse(res.text) which converts it into a JSON which I need from a response body. But if someone knows the solution to original problem, please post.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a generic Serializing object that takes in a dynamic object and returns an HTTPResponseMessage.. Like this C# method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ToJson(dynamic obj)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: It jsut depends on if you are looking for a HTMLResponseMessage, or a JSON object. The C# code above returns an HTMLResponseMessage.